# how to find the most repeat word in string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please tell me how to find the most repeat word in string ?
Example 
If input is this
**"how do you do"**
Output is **"do"**

```
var str="how do you do"
function findMostReaptedWord(str){
    var res = str.split(" ");
    alert(res.length);
    var count;
    var compareString;
    for(var i=0;i<res.length ;i++){
        count=0;
        compareString=res[i]
        for (j=0;i<res.lenth ;j++){
            if(compareString==res[j]){
                count++
            }
        }

    }

}

alert(findMostReaptedWord(str))
```

fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/omjg9v0q/

Comment: What's blocking you from finishing this code ? Any problem ? BTW the usual solution would be to keep an object as map of the counts, the properties being the words.

Comment: ok I will try ...wait for second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave the idea in a comment. Here it is in code :

```
function findMostReaptedWord(str){
    var counts = {}, mr, mc;
    str.match(/\w+/g).forEach(function(w){ counts[w]=(counts[w]||0)+1 });
    for (var w in counts) {
      if (!(counts[w]<mc)) {
        mc = counts[w];
        mr = w;
      }
    }
    return mr;
}
```

A few details :

- I use `str.match(/\w+/g)` for a better decomposition in words. Yours would take anything not a space as a word or part of a word.
- `counts` is a map giving the number of occurrences of each words (i.e. `counts["do"]` is `2`)
- using a map avoids doing two levels of loop, which is very slow

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this solution? possibly with a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Fails for a str that does not have repeated word. Last word is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach

- First, separate the words from the string using Regular Expression.
- Declare an object as a Map which will help you to find the occurrences of each word. (You can use Map Data Structure!)
- Find the most repeated word from that object.

```js
let str = 'How do you do?';
console.log(findMostRepeatedWord(str)); // Result: "do"

function findMostRepeatedWord(str) {
  let words = str.match(/\w+/g);
  console.log(words); // [ 'How', 'do', 'you', 'do' ]

  let occurances = {};

  for (let word of words) {
    if (occurances[word]) {
      occurances[word]++;
    } else {
      occurances[word] = 1;
    }
  }

  console.log(occurances); // { How: 1, do: 2, you: 1 }

  let max = 0;
  let mostRepeatedWord = '';

  for (let word of words) {
    if (occurances[word] > max) {
      max = occurances[word];
      mostRepeatedWord = word;
    }
  }

  return mostRepeatedWord;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I give you an approach,

1. Sort the words first. That way "how do you do" becomes "do do how you".
2. Iterate the string to count the words that repeat, keep the maximum number of times repeating word in memory while iterating.

-
Mebin

Comment: can you please give fiddle

Answer (score -1):

This function may help you

```
function maxWord (str)
{
    var max = 0;
    var maxword = '';
    var words = str.split(' ');
    for(i=0;i<words.length;i++)
    {
        var count = 0;
        var word = '';
        for(j=0;j<words.length;j++)
        {
            if(j !== i && words[i] === words[j])
            {
                count++;
                word = words[i];
            }
        }
        if(count>maxword)
        {
            max = count;
            maxword = word;
        }
    }
    return maxword;
}
maxWord('how do you do'); // returns do
```